# Installing BouncyCastle for NetBeans project

Tags: maven, netbeans, cryptography, bouncycastle, netbeans-platform

So I am trying to install the BouncyCastle Cryptographic API into my NetBeans project, but have run into some problems. I've read some online tutorials on this, but all are rather outdated, and unfortunately have not worked when I've tried them. For example, when I try to add the BouncyCastle JAR (bcprov-jdk15on-153.jar) directly to my NetBeans project's libraries, the project will compile, but when I run the following lines of code:

```
if (Security.getProvider("BC") == null){
    System.out.println("Bouncy Castle provider is NOT available");
}
else{
    System.out.println("Bouncy Castle provider is available");
}
```

(with the import java.security.Security;), it will return the "NOT" available String.

When I try to add the JAR to the JDK and JRE, while also modifying the java.security folders to have: security.provider.N=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider, and then build the project, I get a compilation error saying "error opening zip file" in NetBeans.

I have also tried this entire process using the Lightweight API zip file (rather than the BC Provider), and get the same issues.

I'm using JDK 1.8, and the most recent version of BouncyCastle JAR/zips.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you replace N with a number? N is just the priority of the provider, the providers have all been numbered. Note that you can also simply perform `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider())` in a static initializer. Duplicates won't be added, so you can have this spread out in your code.

Comment: Yes I did replace N with a number (11 in my case). And I also have tried Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()) to statically initialize it, but that requires an import (which I believe is: import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider) - and then it says that I need to search for the Dependency at Maven Repositories, and when I do that, it says "No matching items".